# Is it possible to use jquery i18n translations inside HTML attributes?

Tags: jquery, localization, internationalization

I'm using jquery i18n for localization on a website. On a form on my site, I wish to translate the placeholder attribute and value attribute inside a form. For example:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" name="EMAIL" required="required">
<input type="submit" value="SIGN UP">
```

How can I use data-i18n="" to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript (e.g. jquery) to localize the placeholder attribute, like:

```
$("[name='EMAIL']").attr("placeholder", $.i18n("enter_your_email"));
```